# What's the current, "correct" way to bundle gems for a Rails app with system-wide RVM-installed Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, rubygems

I got ruby installed system-wide by doing:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
```

and then:

```
sudo /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install 2.0.0
```

I'm still not positive that was actually correct, but it seems to have worked. It created an `rvm` group. I've added my user account to it, and re-logged in. Now I need to `bundle install` the gems for my Rails app. This is as close as I can get:

```
david@excelsior:/data/webapps/accountability$ sudo /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481@global/bin/bundle
/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

In the past, I've just done all of this stuff as root, but the rvm website spends a lot of time telling me that this (and rvmsudo) is "wrong" for system-wide operations. So I want to try doing it "right" this time, but I can't find where they've indicated how I *should* be doing it. It would seem that this simple operation would be front-and-center. Maybe I'm just blind?

Comment: My goal here is to deploy multiple Rails apps in, say, /data/webapps, all with their own versions of Ruby and various gems, and serve those apps with a standard Apache/Passenger install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to use `sudo`, it should be enough to be in `rvm` group, just make sure you are in it with `id`.

as for the bundle command, I assume you do not `rvm use 2.0.0-p481` before running the `bundle`, so instead of the `bin/bundle` you should be running wrapper which takes care of loading proper ruby environment for you:

```
/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bundle
```